# RelativeLayout addRule not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Guys I have a cardview and I want to add 2 button on it with rule but **addRule()** method is not working. In the picture, figure A is occurring but I want to make figure B, I mean, I want the buttons set align_parent_right and align_parent_bottom and the second button adjacent to first one. When I run it, figure A occuring. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) iView.getLayoutParams();        
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/4,height/5);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/4,height/5);

removeButton=new Button(mContext);
modifyButton=new Button(mContext);

lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

cardView.setLayoutParams(rl);

cardView.addView(removeButton,lparams);
cardView.addView(modifyButton,lparams2);
```

Comment: Are you adding those buttons to an actual RelativeLayout? If you're just adding them to a CardView widget from the support library that will not work as the CardView is not a RelativeLayout.

Comment: LayoutParams refer to direct parent, you're adding buttons in a CardView. If possible, make it with xml, you can include buttons in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams cardParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        cardView.setLayoutParams(cardParams);
        mainLayout.addView(cardView);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        cardView.addView(relativeLayout);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);

        Button removeButton = new Button(this);
        Button modifyButton = new Button(this);

        removeButton.setText("Remove");
        modifyButton.setText("Modify");

        linearLayout.addView(removeButton);
        linearLayout.addView(modifyButton);
```

Comment: I'm making card programmatically

Comment: Updated my code. Making cardview  programmatically. Try this.